# Python, numpy.array slicing, altering array values with slices

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, slice

I have a Task for numerical integration in which we approximate integral with quadrature formula. My problem is that the task needs me to avoid loops and use vectorized variant, which would be a slice?!

I have np.array object with n values and i have to alter each value of this array using a specific formula. The problem is that the value of this array at point i ist used in the formula to alter the position in. With a for loop it would be easy:

```
x = np.array([...])
for i in range(0,n):
   x[i]=f(x[i]+a)*b`
```

(a,b some othe variables)
How do i do this with slices? I Have to do this for all elements of the array so it would be something like:

```
x[:]=f(x[???]+a)*b
```

And how do i get the right position from my array in to the formula? A slicing instruction like x[:] just runs through my whole object. Is there a way to somehow save the index i am currently at?
I tried to search but found nothing. The other problem is that i do not even know how to properly put the search request...

Comment: Post a real example we can follow. What are you working with and what have you tried. For example, it would be impossible to answer this question effectively without knowing what `f` is.

Comment: F is just a function.   f= lambda x: np.sin(x)

Comment: Simply  `y = np.sin(x + a) * b`.    No need to use slice notation unless you are going to be operating on a sub-part of `x`

Comment: You do realize that `np.sin` is a fully vectorized function?

Comment: Ok here goes the try to explain my problem. (i am not a niteve speaker, so excuse language mistakes).

Comment: I have an interval which has to be cut in picies. x = np.linspace(start,end,pieceAmount). i have my function f. and i have a quadrature formula which approximates my integral value. Quadrature consists of different values b (weights or factors) and c (function values). and the integratin formula is: calculate for ech x from my linspace the sum of b1*f(x[i]+c1)+...+bn*f(x[i]+cn) and after that i have to summ all of this new calculated values. So my new value a position x[i] depends on the old one

Comment: x[:]=np.sum(  b[:]*f(x[:]+*c[:])  )is what i tried but it is wrong

Answer (score 0):

You may be confusing two issues

- modifying all elements of an array
- calculating values for all elements of an array

In

```
x = np.array([...])
for i in range(0,n):
   x[i]=f(x[i]+a)*b`
```

you change elements of `x` one by one, and also pass them one by one to `f`.

`x[:] = ...` lets you change all elements of `x` at once, but the source (the right hand side of the equation) has to generate all those values.  But usually you don't need to assign values. Instead just use `x = ...`.  It's just as fast and memory efficient.

Using `x[:]` on the RHS does nothing for you.  If `x` is a list this makes a copy; if `x` is an array is just returns a `view`, an array with the same values.

The key question is, what does your `f(...)` function accept?  If it uses operations like `+`, `*` and functions like `np.sin`, you can give it an array, and it will return an array.

But if it only works with scalars (that includes using functions like `math.sin`), the you have to feed it scalars, i.e. `x[i]`.

Let's try to unpack that comment (which might be better as an edit to the original question)

I have an interval which has to be cut in picies.

```
x = np.linspace(start,end,pieceAmount)
function f
quadrature formula
b (weights or factors)
c (function values)
b1*f(x[i]+c1)+...+bn*f(x[i]+cn)
```

For example

```
In [1]: x = np.arange(5)
In [2]: b = np.arange(3)
In [6]: c = np.arange(4,7)*.1
```

We can do the `x[i]+c` for all `x` and `c` with broadcasting

```
In [7]: xc = x + c[:,None]
In [8]: xc
Out[8]: 
array([[ 0.4,  1.4,  2.4,  3.4,  4.4],
       [ 0.5,  1.5,  2.5,  3.5,  4.5],
       [ 0.6,  1.6,  2.6,  3.6,  4.6]])
```

If `f` is a function like `np.sin` that takes any array, we can pass `xc` to that, getting back a like sized array.

Again with broadcasting we can do the `b[n]*f(x[i]+c[n])` calculation

```
In [9]: b[:,None]* np.sin(xc)
Out[9]: 
array([[ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        , -0.        , -0.        ],
       [ 0.47942554,  0.99749499,  0.59847214, -0.35078323, -0.97753012],
       [ 1.12928495,  1.99914721,  1.03100274, -0.88504089, -1.98738201]])
```

and then we can sum, getting back an array shaped just like `x`:

```
In [10]: np.sum(_, axis=0)
Out[10]: array([ 1.60871049,  2.99664219,  1.62947489, -1.23582411, -2.96491212])
```

That's the dot or matrix product:

```
In [11]: b.dot(np.sin(xc))
Out[11]: array([ 1.60871049,  2.99664219,  1.62947489, -1.23582411, -2.96491212])
```

And as I noted earlier we can complete the action with

```
x = b.dot(f(x+c[:,None])
```

The key to a simple expression like this is `f` taking an array.